# C# Returning Types from a method

Tags: c#, methods

If I have a method that returns a datagridview and the flow is similar to this:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
        {
            SharedMethods.updateStatus("There are no excluded results to display");
            //return dgv;
        }
        else
        {
            dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            return dgv;
        }
```

If the if condition is true then I do not want to return a datagridview(as there is no data), what can I return in this case?  If I return null, then the calling method has a null datagridview that causes later problems.

Thanks.

Comment: If y ou want to return nothing or a database, dont use it as a database method.  Just make it void and have it fill a general property or not.

Comment: You should handle it in calling code anyway. It's correct.

Comment: Set the Visible property to false.

Comment: @Hans, thanks. Works perfectly and is very simple.  If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the grid's Visible property to false if you have nothing to show.

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. throw an exception
2. `null` and add special case handling for `null` to the caller
3. If DataGridView supports it, an empty list

You usually use 3) with `IEnumerables<T>`, but I don't know if your return type supports it. This solution is best if you want your to behave the same way in your first case as if you got no results from your query.

Comment: I think that the best option here is 3.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the return type of the method to return an error code (`enum`) and have the `DataGridView` as an `out` or `ref` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two solutions:

1. Return a null `DataGridView` and modify your calling code with that.
2. Return a `DataGridView` but with a null `DataSource` (as there's no data) and make sure your calling code can cope with that.

Personally I'd go with 2. You still have a *view* but no *data*, so you still need a `DataGridView` but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would not return anything from a data binding method. Why do you need that? (This code won't even compile because the true block has nothing to return.)

Simply make it a method.